# Why won't Teracopy software work only when I paste files into an android external memory card?

Tags: usb, memory, android

I have pasted some songs into my android external memory card using my pc; where I had initially installed Teracopy software. However, it won't work. Instead, the default copying of Windows kicks in.

[image]

Why won't Teracopy software work **only when** I paste files into an android external memory card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Android device doesn't present itself to Windows as a USB Mass-storage device (AKA USB stick or USB harddisk) but as a so-called MTP device.
This is fairly normal for smartphones and also many photo-cameras.

Teracopy only works with mass-storage devices. (Anything that you can assign a drive-letter to. You can't do that with a MTP device.)

It you want to use TeraCopy you will have to pull the SD card from the device and hook it up to your computer using a flah-card reader. (Provided it is formatted in FAT or NTFS so  Windows can read it. The MTP mechanism takes care of translation of the filesystem so Windows doesn't need to know in what format the Android device internally likes to store things.)

Comment: Windows can read and write to any ext[2][3][4] variant via Paragon's [LinuxFs](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/).  _(Newer versions of Android may format external cards as ext3/ext4 - it depends on how the OEM/carrier customized the OS.)_

Comment: Minor point, MPT should actually be MTP. It is the [Media Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) that is used. That is unless you were wanting to blame some [audio module tracker software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMPT) for the weirdness. Other than that this is the answer, there is nothing for Teracopy because it is not a "standard" file transfer.

Comment: @Mokubai Your absolutely right. My bad. I will correct my answer.

Comment: @JW0914 on stock Android SD card is formatted as `ext4` only when used as Adoptable Storage, which has its second partition (or filesystem) encrypted. So you need to take care of encryption before (or after) mounting filesystem. // @Tonny just to add, on rooted devices it's still possible to expose a block device as UMS.

Comment: @IrfanLatif As mentioned, it depends on the configuration of Android by the OEM & Carrier, as well as what version of Android it is.  For example, since Oreo (v15) on stock Android, the `/data` partition is ext4 with `/data/media` being emulated as [SDCardFS](https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead/).  When `/data` is formatted (factory reset), it's re-formatted as ext4 _(or in the case of LineageOS, `rm -rf` is executed in lieu of formatting, excluding `/data/media`)_

Comment: @JW0914 I was talking about physically external SD card explicitly. `ext4` support for `/data` was added in Android 1.5, not Android 8 (Oreo): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/026f1451ce0c92c4630ca2d2d95f2fb9d68e9568